# PHP - Convert string to date in

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am getting a string like **Wed Sep 28 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)** and I need to convert it to **2016-09-28 01:00:00** 
I have tried this

```
$startTime   = strtotime($updatedData['start']);
echo $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$startTime);
```

but it returns me **2016-09-27 20:00:00**

Comment: This is because of the timezone, the time is +5 but the result is +0.

Comment: check your timezone

Comment: Your out put date is in GMT. So please set the time_zone and run the script

Comment: set the timezone before start converting. `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dili")`, and convert using the format. For the format use **Ex:** `DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009'); echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change it to use `DateTime`:

```
$startTime = new DateTime('Wed Sep 28 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)');
echo $startTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

DateTime keeps the timezone you give him.

Live Example: https://3v4l.org/UTltO

Comment: exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

@copynpaste solution is nice and straight forward but I will still share my solution by using Carbon.

Carbon is a library included together with laravel and here is the 
[documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

```
$carbon = new Carbon('Wed Sep 28 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)');
$carbon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $carbon;
```

it will come out the result same as DateTime

```
2016-09-28 01:00:00
```

So what carbon nice is you can just add day, minute, second and etc by just a very minimal code, here is an example:

```
$carbon->addDays(1);
echo $carbon;

//result
2016-09-29 01:00:00
```

Comment: +1 I like this answer better as the question is tagged laravel and this answer gives a way to do it using carbon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$startTime   = strtotime($updatedData['start']);
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$startTime);
echo date( "Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime( $time) + 5 * 3600 );
```

It returns UTC time and you do need to add 5 hours to it. Also a quick suggestion. You can use Carbon for handling the date time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the desired time zone before converting. Please see the below code as a reference.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
$str = 'Wed Sep 28 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)';
$startTime   = strtotime($str);
echo $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$startTime);
```